# Thread adapters larger than 1/2"

Tags: mechanical-engineering, machining, fasteners, bolting

I have a 1/2-20 stud that I need to step up to a 3/4-16 stud. I searched around for 1/2-20 female to 3/4-16 male thread adapters, but was only able to find such a product on McMaster for sizes 1/2 and smaller. Are there "thread adapters" (assuming that's what they're called) for larger sizes? If so, does anyone know where I can buy them?

[image]

Comment: Local machine shop & make one. Or you could.

Comment: Sounds like you are describing a male-female standoff with different threads on the two ends. In the sizes you're looking at it may well be a custom job. If a standard product existed, you may still be limited by the thread length or thread depth.

Comment: Large is relative; I think of 24" diameter adapters , called crossovers for well casing.

Comment: Yeah, this might be a custom job, which I won't be able to do myself. If I go to a machine shop, what kind of lead time should I expect from your average machinist? Is this a couple hour job...full day...couple days? I just want to get an idea of how to budget time for this product.

Comment: Pay premium rates and you might get premium service... Know the machinist and it may happen even quicker... Shout and scream it will be a week...